# How do I interpret the CPLEX Optimization Studio MIP gap output?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, cplex

I'm having difficulties understanding my FlowControl output compared to what the Engine Log shows me.

[image: Scripting Log (left) and Engine Log (right)]

My output from the FlowControl into the Scripting Log (yellow marks) is `cplex.getObjValue()`, then `cplex.getBestObjValue()`, and `cplex.getMIPRelativeGap()`. The Engine log shows the last entry before the optimization is terminated. I have a `dettillim = 15000`, which doesn't seem to be reached, but also a few fixed binary variables (LB==UB), so I'm expecting a gap.

Now my question is why (and/or how) does the MIP gap extracted from the FlowControl differ from the last entry in the Engine Log? I can't find any reasonable explanation in the documentation.

Comment: Is it possible that the engine log does not print every single line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The engine log does not print the gap for every node cplex investigates. That would leave you with more than 2000 lines in the log for your instance. So cplex has done some work between the last line in the engine log and the time it terminates.

I must admit I do not know anything about the frequency with which cplex outputs a line in the engine log. It might be node or time specific?

Comment: By default the output is node specific, plus a line for each integer feasible solution. It is configurable with the [MIPInterval](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/MIPInterval.html) parameter. Additionally the [MIPDisplay](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/MIPDisplay.html) parameter must be greater than 1 in order for node logs to appear.

Comment: @MichaelChan Thanks, very useful, I didn't know

Comment: Thank you both! Too bad it doesn't at least print the final values automatically when the solver terminates before reaching optimality...